# Why won't print.scss load compass/reset on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, compass-geolocation

On localhost, Compass works perfectly. `screen.scss` loads `compass/reset` just fine. So does `print.scss`.

On Heroku, screen.scss still works, but `print.scss` gives this error:

```
Error compiling CSS asset
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset.
Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(/app/app/assets/stylesheets/print.scss)
(in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/print.scss)
/app/app/assets/stylesheets/print.scss:1
```

Why? How do I fix it?

Relevant lines from relevant files...

**Gemfile**:

```
gem "compass"
gem "pg"
gem "sass"
gem "sass-rails"
gem "haml"
gem "haml-rails"
gem "susy"
# gem "thin"
gem "unicorn"
gem "pdfkit"
gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"

group :assets do
  gem "sass-rails"
  gem "coffee-rails"
  gem "compass-rails"
  gem "compass-susy-plugin"
end
```

**config/application.rb**:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
end

module Testivate
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"    
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
    config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware", :print_media_type => true        
  end
end
```

**/config/environments/production.rb**:

```
Testivate::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
end
```

**/app/assets/stylsheets/screen.scss** (first line):

```
@import "compass/reset";
```

**/app/assets/stylesheets/print.scss** (first line):

```
@import "compass/reset";
```

**/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.ui.core
 *= require screen
*/
```

**/app/views/reviews/print.html** (as compiled from `print.html.haml`):

```
<head>
<link href="/assets/print.css" media="print, screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

**/app/views/reviews/show.html** (as compiled from `show.html.haml`):

```
<head>
<link href="/assets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not precompiling your assets locally before deploying to heroku?

Comment: Because (a) not precompiling didn't seem to be causing me any problems, and (b) precompiling put a bunch of precompiled assets in /public/ which clashed with the assets in /asset/ when I viewed my app on localhost. Do you think this could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on the [55 Minutes](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/04/untangling-the-rails-asset-pipeline-part-4-troubleshooting/#main-stylesheet-works) blog:

> By default, Rails only precompiles application.css. If you have
>   additional stylesheets, like perhaps ie.css or print.css, these won’t
>   be precompiled unless you explicitly tell Rails to do so.
>
> `config.assets.precompile += ['ie.css', 'print.css']`